# Live/interactive elements in browser tab bars

Tags: gui-design, terminology, tabs, browser

I saw another interesting example of an interactive/live UI element in browser tab bars recently, this time it is a [%scrolled value](https://www.knutmelvaer.no/blog/2020/05/how-i-put-the-scroll-percentage-in-the-title-bar/) for a page.

[image]

A very popular and common example I have seen previously was the number of unread emails displayed for mail applications running in a browser (e.g. Gmail).

[image]

Is there a term used for these type of UI elements specifically designed for the browser tab? The term favicon was used specifically for the browser tabs, so I wonder if the same applies to UI elements of this type.

Comment: Favicon is a shortened version of "Favourite Icon", originally used for the Favourites (bookmark) feature in Internet Explorer. It took many years after that use for tabs to become a thing but the popularity of the favicon meant there was already a handy resource for decorating the tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Flashing Tab

These types of notifications are usually called **flashing notifications** or in the cases of the favicon, **Notification alert**.

By extension, the case of tabs can be called **Flashing Tabs**

[image]

*Image from [Create a Flashing Notification Tab](https://curtistimson.co.uk/post/js/create-a-flashing-tab-notification-page-title/)*

Or **[Browser Tab Notifications](https://support.zipwhip.com/s/article/Browser-Tab-Notifications)**

Comment: +1 so it seems like there are definitely quite a few types of behaviour/interaction that exists on these tabs.

Answer (score 4):

The particular one that you have mentioned in the question do not have a name by definition as of now it seems.
Anyways, from a technical side it is adding JS functions to `document.title`. Therefore maybe we can call it **Dynamic Document Title**. *[from today haha]*

*Please post your answers if it actually has a defined name. Then I shall remove my answer :)*

Also, I'm posting this dynamic favicon of Google Calendar which might be of your interest. The favicon's date changes to the current date.

[image]

Comment: +1 I like the suggestion, but maybe it's a bit too 'techy' to catch on? I have noticed the dynamic favicon, and that's a good one to call out too :)

Comment: It we were to implement changing icon, we would call the task “implement dynamic page Icon”, as the subject is “page title” and “page icon”.

Comment: I think Dynamic Tab Title is a pretty good compromise between what a developer and designer would recognize, so thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised I can't see any formal UX description or testing for these anywhere. I did see a couple of articles on creating them which referred to them as Update Notifications.

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-display-update-notifications-in-the-browser-tab--cms-23458

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications/update

Comment: +1 I guess it makes sense in a way because the implementation of that particular feature in the browser tab is like a notification. The example with the %scrolled is more like a live/interaction element, so there are definitely some variations around and perhaps it belongs in a bigger group/family of UI elements.